# How do you derive $v_f^2 = 2ad + v_i^2$ from $v_f = v_i + at$ and $d = v_it + (a/2)t^2$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, calculus

I'm trying to use substitution to find the equation Vf^2 = 2ad + Vi^2 from Vf = Vi + at and d = Vit + a/2(t^2), but I get stuck understanding part of the math. I've attached a picture, and you can see that when I multiply all terms by 2a, I don't understand why the a inside the brackets in the numerator of the last term (circled) somehow cancels out and doesn't make it to the next step. Shouldn't it stay there, mathematically (since it's in the numerator and can't cancel out by multiplying 2a)?

(I use Vo as Vi and V as Vf)

[image: work]

Comment: Perhaps the $a^2$ in the denominator of that term is the culprit.

Comment: solve t form $v_f=v_i+at$ and substitute it in $d=v_i\,t+(a/2)t^2$ rearge you get your equation

Comment: @Eli that's what I did, but I'm stuck on understanding how the rearranging works.

Comment: @J.Murray what do you mean by that?

Comment: @john this is a pure Algebra calculation, please try again, step by step

Answer (score 0):

I'll get you half way there.  Note that there are only two "original" kinematic equations:

$\Delta x = \frac{1}{2}(v_i + v_f) \Delta t \qquad (1)$

$v_f=v_i + a \Delta t \qquad (2)$

Solve (1) for $\Delta t$ and substitute into (2)

$v_f = v_i + a \frac{2 \Delta x}{(v_i + v_f)} \qquad (3)$

$v_f - v_i = a \frac{2 \Delta x}{v_i + v_f} \qquad (4)$

Now, clean up (4) algebraically to arrive at the desired equation.

Comment: The way I learned it, the 2 kinematics equations are the ones I wrote in the quetsion title. I'm not sure where you got those 2 original kinematics equations.

Comment: Those two equations come from the definition of average velocity and the definition of average acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

The term that you're struggling with is
$$ 2a \cdot \frac{a}{2} \left(\frac{v-v_0}{a}\right)^2 = a^2 \cdot \frac{(v-v_0)^2}{a^2} = (v-v_0)^2$$